# Accept button in email message that triggers a process in salesforce to update case record

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template, apex-email-service, email-alert

I would like to know if it's possible to have Accept or Reject button in email message that a recipient can click then will trigger an update process (WF, PB or Flow) in a case record? The email that the recipient (customer) will receive is from Workflow Email Alert then they will respond by clicking the Accept or Reject button.

At the background, that action should trigger a process in Salesforce that will update a case record.

Thank you

Comment: Questions that can be answered with a simple yes/no aren't a great fit for the format of this site. There is probably some way to do this using a public site or email-to-case, but emails read outside of SFDC have basically no connection to Salesforce.